# JSF / Richfaces : how to retrieve the backing bean property that served as value for a inputtext

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Hie all,

I have a complex form with a list of inputs (inputtext) that have been generated using a foreach over a backing bean property (list).

```
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.list}" var="elem">
<h:inputText value="#{elem.val}">
<a4j:ajax render="@this"/>
</h:inputText>
</c:forEach>
```

When one input is changed, I would like to know which one it was, so that I can proceed some immediate update on my model (ie call some update methods in a backing EJB).
I have been looking through ValueChangeEvent, AjaxBehaviorEvent, IUComponent... but did not find where I cloud get a direct reference back to my backing property...

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add a a4j:support like this?

```
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.list}" var="elem">
   <h:inputText value="#{elem.val}">
      <a4j:ajax event="onchange" listner="#{someBean.changeValue(elem)}" render="@this"/>
   </h:inputText>
</c:forEach>
```

This way you can get, into the changeValue method, a reference to the element.

Comment: Yes this is the solution I came to at some time between my question and your answer when I realized that listeners could get parameters...
Thanks!